# Find command which makes directory and copies file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, find

I was trying to use the find command to find some files using an expression and create those particular directories in a destination folder and copy the respective files.

```
find /home  -type f -mmin -60
```

The above prints some files on the terminal which have some files under nested directories and I want to create these additional directories under output/ in the same hierarchy structure

```
find /home  -type f -mmin -60 -execdir sh -c 'mkdir -p 'output/$0' && cp "$1" "output/$0"' sh {} \;
```

This does not work at all and acts pretty weirdly

Comment: I think the string that starts with a single quote ends in an unintended place because there is another single quote.

Comment: There's no need to spawn a shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `install` command:

```
find /home -type f -mmin -60 -exec install -D -m644 {} output/{} \;
```

It transparently copy files and run `mkdir` under the hood.

Comment: Thank you, I had one follow up question - the find gets the absolute path above and creates directories according to that, is there a way to get the relative paths and do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are some misplaced quotes that mean the first `$0` is actually the top-level shell `$0` (maybe the path to the program).  `$0`, properly quoted, within the `-execdir` command isn't useful because it always expands to `sh` (because of `... sh {} \;`.  This may be closer to what you want:

```
find .  -type f -mmin -60 -execdir sh -c 'mkdir -p "output/$1" && cp -- "$1" "output/$1"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: No need to spawn a _subshell_ here ;)

Comment: @GillesQuénot, agreed.  I just wanted to show minimal changes to 
 fix the problems with the given code.